# Racket или Scheme найти производную от простой функции

Tags: lisp, функциональное-программирование, scheme, racket

Всем привет!
Мне нужно реализовать функцию на языке Racket, которая вычисляет производную от простых математических выражений с одной переменной. Функция должна принимать 2 аргумента – математическое выражение со стандартным синтаксисом языка Scheme, содержащее числа, атомы (константы и переменные) и функции +, -, *, /, expt (возведение в степень числа e). Второй аргумент – переменная по которой необходимо произвести дифференцирование. Другие символы в выражении считаются константами.
Может быть кто то сталкивался с подобной задачей и знает как решать или с чего начать? Или может быть есть какая то статья посвященная дифференцированию на функциональных языках. Обшарил весь гугл, ничего подобного не нашел. Интересует алгоритм на функциональном языке, это может быть Lisp, Scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел подробное решение это задачи
http://www.cyberforum.ru/lisp/thread1758457.html

Вот как выглядит код на языке Lisp

```
(defun deriv (f x)
  (cond ((numberp f) 0)
        ((eq f x) 1)
        ((eq (car f) '+) `(+ ,(deriv (cadr f) x) ,(deriv (caddr f) x)))
        ((eq (car f) '-) `(- ,(deriv (cadr f) x) ,(deriv (caddr f) x)))
        ((eq (car f) '*) `(+ (* ,(caddr f) ,(deriv (cadr f) x)) (* ,(cadr f) ,(deriv (caddr f) x))))
        ((eq (car f) 'sin) `(* (cos ,(cadr f)) ,(deriv (cadr f) x)))
        ((eq (car f) 'cos) `(* (- (cos ,(cadr f)) ,(deriv (cadr f) x))))
        ((eq (car f) 'exp) `(* (exp ,(cadr f)) (deriv (cadr f) x)))
        ((eq (car f) '^) `(* (* ,(caddr f) (^ ,(cadr f) (- ,(caddr f) 1))) ,(deriv (cadr f) x)))))
```